# Exception 400081 while downloading a view using TableauServerClient

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am using TableauServerClient (0.8) in a Python (3.7.1) script to download a view as .csv from Tableau server (2019.1.3 (20191.19.0417.1429) 64-bit Windows) onto my local machine. My code works for most of the views but for some views, I am getting following error:

```
tableauserverclient.server.endpoint.exceptions.ServerResponseError:

400081: Bad Request

There was a problem querying the data for view 'xyz'
```

Has someone faced this issue in the past? Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, we are going to need a way to reproduce your error, and cannot solve the issue without one.

Comment: This error usually comes when querying with wrong URL. Please provide more information for us to help you better

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar error & neither the documentation of Python API nor the REST API had any info about this issue. ( I couldn't even find the API response error code in either)

But after a long search, I stumbled upon a suggestion by the user 'gaoang2148' in [this thread](https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/issues/238).

**For me, the error was occurring because a few data sources in my workbook were missing connection credentials** *( The credentials were missing after I published an update from Tableau Desktop).* Once I embedded the credentials for each data source, the code was working fine again. i was able to pull & download data from tableau views via API.

Answer (score 1):

When I have run into this, it’s been on newly published views. I believe it has to do with Tableau's behind the scenes managing of views and/or data in the repository. Sometimes it takes an hour or two for a new view that's been published to query properly from TSC. Manually navigating to the view in browser also might force the view to be processed, but that could've been coincidence when it's happened to me. It usually resolves itself within an hour.

Comment: You are making an assumption that some of the data/views are more recent than others, which may be correct, but you should clarify with OP that this is the case.